# Removing a Button from Customized Excel Ribbon

Tags: excel, ribbon

I have a problem with Excel customized ribbon.

The file I'm using has a customized ribbon and I need to edit/remove it but I can't find it in the ''Main Tabs'' available, but still I do not have the option to remove/edit it.

Any clues on this?

[image: Excel customized ribbon]

I tried using "Customize the Ribbon" options to remove it, but the button name (CEAF) dose not appear between the ''Main Tabs'' available. Also, I tried to use the ''Quick access Toolbar'', this time the customized ribbon name appeared (Upadacitinib CEA Tab) in the commands and this specific button (CEAF) also appeared, but still I don not have the option to remove/edit it.

[image: Quick access Toolbar]

Comment: You can to do it by edit UI xml file
1)Rename your file extension from .xlsx/.xlsm to .zip
2)Open it like folder and go to CustomUI subfolder
3)Edit the ui xml file there and save it
4)Rename back to origin extension